# Facing .save issue while trying to save a pyspark DF in CSV format

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark

I have a list of dataset_ids that is passed to the following script through an orchestrational python script using a for loop. The same SparkSession is used throughout both the code. The following code performs some transformation and produces a finalDF which is to be saved in a CSV format on S3 bucket.

```
import os
import traceback

import boto3

from db_functions import db_functions
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from datetime import datetime
from time import gmtime, strftime


s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
paginator = s3.get_paginator("list_objects")

db_schema = "specdb_orch"
table_workflow_log_table = "wkfl_step_execn_log"
table_workflow_config = "cntl_wkfl_cfgrn"
table_global_variable = "cntl_gbl_var"
table_ref_data = "ref_data"
table_ref_data_col = "ref_data_col"

todays_date = strftime("%Y_%m_%d", gmtime())
now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
get_last_modified = lambda obj: int(obj['LastModified'].strftime('%s'))

# custom function to perform CRUD operation on the RDS Database
db_orion = db_functions()


def main_execution(SparkSession, dataset_id, cycl_id):
    try:

        print("INSIDE VENDOR TRANSFORMATION ")

        spark = SparkSession.builder \
            .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 1) \
            .config('spark.rpc.message.maxSize', '256').getOrCreate()
        print('SPARK version: ' + str(spark.sparkContext.version))
        spark.catalog.clearCache()

        # some unrelated code
        # ****

        # reads S3 bucket with CSV files for performing transformation
        page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=sourcecentric_prefix)
        for page in page_iterator:
            if "Contents" in page:
                print('Contents are available')
                all_added = [obj for obj in page["Contents"] if obj['Size'] != 0]

                if bool(all_added):
                    print("Iterating Contents")
                    myDf = spark.createDataFrame(all_added)
                    myDf.cache()
                    df1 = myDf.withColumn("folder", f.reverse(f.split(myDf['Key'], '/'))[1])
                    folder_list = df1.select("folder").distinct().collect()
                    print(f"folder_list: {folder_list}")
                    for folder in folder_list:
                        print(f"folder: {folder}")
                        temp_file_list = df1.where(df1.folder == str(folder.folder)).select('Key').distinct().collect()
                        mystring = "s3a://" + bucket + '/'
                        study_arr = [(mystring + s.Key) for s in temp_file_list]
                        print(f"study_arr: {study_arr}")
                        agg_df_trans = spark.read.format('csv') \
                            .option("multiline", "true") \
                            .option("quote", '"') \
                            .option("escape", '"').load(study_arr, header='true')

                        agg_df_trans.createOrReplaceTempView((str(folder.folder) + str(dataset_id)))

        # Read s3 reference csv files for performing joins with the main DF
        df_lis = {}
        for each in ref_data:
            df_name = f"{each['df_nm']}_{each['dtst_id']}_{each['seq_num']}"
            if df_name not in df_lis:
                df_lis.update({df_name: []})

            page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket=each['file_path'].split('/')[2],
                                               Prefix=each['file_path'].split('/', 3)[3])

            last_added = ""
            for page in page_iterator:
                print("Inside page_iterator loop")
                if "Contents" in page:
                    last_added = [obj['Key'] for obj in sorted(page["Contents"], key=get_last_modified)][-1]
                else:
                    print("No files in the location")

            if last_added:
                print(f"last_added: {last_added}")
                ref_filename = os.path.basename(last_added)
                df_lis[df_name].append(f"{each['file_path']}{ref_filename}")
            else:
                print("No latest reference file present in the location")
        print(f'list of temp dataframes to be created: {df_lis}')

        for k, v in df_lis.items():
            ref_df = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").option("quote", '"').option("escape", '"').format(
                'csv').load(v, header='true')
            ref_df.createOrReplaceTempView(k)
            print(f"Temp dataframe(s) created for: {k}")
        print("Completed creation of temp view")

        fetch_intmd2_path_query = """select val from %s.cntl_gbl_var where glbl_varb = 'intermediate_appcentric'""" % (
            db_schema)
        intmd_path_query = db_orion.execute_query(fetch_intmd2_path_query)
        # Create loaders for
        failed_loader = []
        # dts_type is a list of loaders(csv files) details fetched from RDS table 
        for loaders in dts_type:
            print(f'printing each loader: {loaders}')
            split_col = loaders['split_col']
            print(f"split_col: {split_col}")
            loader_name = loaders['load_nm']
            print(f"loader_name: {loader_name}")
            try:

                sql_condition_val = ref_check(db_orion, spark, dataset_id, vendor_name)
                print(f"sql_condition_val:  {sql_condition_val}")

                # loader['dsrc_qry'] returns the transformation SQL query
                if (len(sql_condition_val) > 0):
                    new_sql = "SELECT * FROM (" + loaders['dsrc_qry'] + ")NA WHERE " + sql_condition_val
                    final_df = spark.sql(new_sql)
                else:
                    print("Executing sql without ref logic.")
                    final_df = spark.sql(loaders['dsrc_qry'])

            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Exception for loader {loader_name}: {e}")
                failed_loader.append(loader_name)
                continue

            BASE_TARGET = intmd_path_query[0]['val'] + 'operations/' + data_dtl['dsrc']
            print(f'BASE_TARGET: {BASE_TARGET}')

            filename = 's3a://' + bucket + '/' + BASE_TARGET + loader_name + '_/' + 'file1'
            print(f'printing filename: {filename}')
            final_df = final_df.select([f.col(col).alias(col.replace('_', ' ')) for col in final_df.columns])
            print("replaced _ before saving")
            try:
                # repartioning value
                temp_df = final_df.repartition(1).write.partitionBy(split_col) \
                    .option("header", "true") \
                    .option("multiline", "true") \
                    .option("quote", '"') \
                    .option("escape", '"') \
                    .option("nullValue", None) \
                    .option("emptyValue", None)
                print(f"Partion done: {final_df}")

                total_record_count = final_df.count()
                print(f"total_record_count: {total_record_count}")

                # ERROR IN EXECUTING THE FOLLOWING LINE
                temp_df.format("csv").save(filename)

                print("executed the save")
            except Exception as sdf:
                print(f"exception in saving df: {sdf}")
                raise Exception(str(sdf))

        if bool(failed_loader):
            raise Exception(f'Failed to execute loader(s) {failed_loader} ')

        print("COMPLETED VENDOR TRANSFORMATION")
        return {"exitCode": 0, "status_code": 200, "exceptionMessage": "Data transformation completed"}
    except Exception as e:
        print("the error occured is %s", str(traceback.format_exc()))
        return {"exitCode": 1, "status_code": 500, "exceptionMessage": str(e)}


def ref_check(db_orion, spark, dataset_id, vendor_name):
    try:
        print("INSIDE ref_check METHOD")
        string_cond = ""
        ref_table_query = f"select colmn_nm,file_path,filename from {db_schema}.{table_ref_data} where dtst_id=0 "
        ref_table = db_orion.execute_query(ref_table_query)
        print(f"ref_table {ref_table}")
        ref_file_path = ref_table[0]['file_path'] + ref_table[0]['filename']
        ref_df = spark.read.csv(ref_file_path, header=True, inferSchema=True)

        print(f"{len(ref_table)} refrence records found.")

        for each_ref_record in range(0, len(ref_table)):
            ref_list = list(ref_df.select(str(ref_table[each_ref_record]['colmn_nm'])).where(
                ref_df.Datasource == vendor_name).toPandas()[str(ref_table[each_ref_record]['colmn_nm'])])
            print(f"ref_list {ref_list}")

            ref_data_col_query = f"select filter_colmn_nm from {db_schema}.{table_ref_data_col} where dtst_id={dataset_id} and colmn_nm='{ref_table[each_ref_record]['colmn_nm']}'"
            ref_data_col_table = db_orion.execute_query(ref_data_col_query)

            if ref_list and ref_data_col_table:
                if (len(string_cond) > 0):
                    ref_string = '\',\''.join(ref_list)
                    string_cond = string_cond + " AND " + str(
                        ref_data_col_table[0]['filter_colmn_nm']) + " IN (" + '\'' + ref_string + '\'' + ")"
                else:
                    ref_string = '\',\''.join(ref_list)
                    string_cond = string_cond + " " + str(
                        ref_data_col_table[0]['filter_colmn_nm']) + " IN (" + '\'' + ref_string + '\'' + ")"
            else:
                print("No ref data found")

        print(f"string_cond : {string_cond}")

        return string_cond

    except Exception as pe:
        print("Exception in ref_check: %s", str(pe))
        raise Exception(pe)
```

The issue with this code is that, when we try to save the final dataframe using .save (added comment on in the above code at the position of this error) spark UDF I get the following error.

```
13/01/2022 14:42:13 INFO INSIDE VENDOR TRANSFORMATION 
13/01/2022 14:42:13 INFO SPARK version: 2.4.3
13/01/2022 14:42:14 INFO STARTED EXECUTE_QUERY  - ( UPDATE specdb_orch.wkfl_step_execn_log SET WKFL_EXECN_STA= 'In Progress',ERR_CD = '', ERR_DS='', MODF_BY = 'specdhub' WHERE WKFL_ID = 3 AND
        dtst_id=7 and wkfl_nm = 'data_transformation' and cycl_id = 20220113  )
 QUERY STRING: UPDATE specdb_orch.wkfl_step_execn_log SET WKFL_EXECN_STA= 'In Progress',ERR_CD = '', ERR_DS='', MODF_BY = 'specdhub' WHERE WKFL_ID = 3 AND
        dtst_id=7 and wkfl_nm = 'data_transformation' and cycl_id = 20220113  
13/01/2022 14:42:14 INFO  COMPLETED  EXECUTE_QUERY  WITH RESULTS : []
13/01/2022 14:42:14 INFO status updated successfully
13/01/2022 14:42:14 INFO STARTED EXECUTE_QUERY  - ( select * from specdb_orch.cntl_dtst_mast where dtst_id = 7; )
 QUERY STRING: select * from specdb_orch.cntl_dtst_mast where dtst_id = 7; 
13/01/2022 14:42:14 INFO  COMPLETED  EXECUTE_QUERY  WITH RESULTS : [{'dtst_id': 7, 'dsrc': 'q2_solutions', 'dtst_nm': 'q2_solutions', 'dsrc_type': 'biomaterial_', 'actv_flag': 'Y', 'src_file_dtl': '[{"filename":"^BMSALL-Q2-CLINVENTORY-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9].csv$", "path":"all/stage/q2solutions/biospecimen-project-72022/biospecimen/raw/"}]', 'load_type': 'full', 'load_sta': 'NULL', 'proc_type': 'join', 'last_load_dtm': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 13, 6, 36, 32), 'inrt_by': 'specdb', 'inrt_dt': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 4, 8, 7, 59), 'modf_by': 'specdb', 'modf_dt': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 4, 8, 7, 59), 'stdy_len': 9, 'delimiter': ',', 'ignore_quote': 'True', 'file_type': 'csv', 'stdy_capture': None, 'rej_path': 'all/reject/q2solutions/biospecimen-project-72022/biospecimen/raw/'}]
13/01/2022 14:42:14 INFO Fetched dataset dtl
13/01/2022 14:42:14 INFO STARTED EXECUTE_QUERY  - ( select * from specdb_orch.cntl_etl_sql where dtst_id = 7 and proc_flag = 'trfmn' and run_flag='Y' )
 QUERY STRING: select * from specdb_orch.cntl_etl_sql where dtst_id = 7 and proc_flag = 'trfmn' and run_flag='Y' 
13/01/2022 14:42:14 INFO  COMPLETED  EXECUTE_QUERY  WITH RESULTS : [{'id': 4, 'dtst_id': 7, 'file_path': 's3a://<bucket>/all/specimen_datahub/q2_tube_type_reference/', 'df_nm': 'ref', 'inrt_by': None, 'inrt_dt': None, 'modf_by': None, 'modf_dt': None, 'seq_num': 1, 'filename': 'q2_tube_type_reference.csv', 'colmn_nm': None, 'src_file': None}]
13/01/2022 14:42:14 DEBUG intermediate_prefix: /gbl/intermediate/specimen_datahub_v010075/sourcecentric/transient/q2_solutions/
13/01/2022 14:42:14 INFO Contents are available
13/01/2022 14:42:14 INFO Iterating Content
a from dict is deprecated,please use pyspark.sql.Row instead
13/01/2022 14:42:20 DEBUG folder_list: [Row(folder='operations')]
13/01/2022 14:42:20 DEBUG folder: Row(folder='operations')
13/01/2022 14:42:20 DEBUG study_arr: ['s3a://dev-dl-data-d2-us-east-1-514827/gbl/intermediate/specimen_datahub_v010075/sourcecentric/transient/q2_solutions/operations/part-00000-c4d5068f-4094-40fb-bcf0-242643cdfb96-c000.csv']
13/01/2022 14:42:22 DEBUG page_iterator: <botocore.paginate.PageIterator object at 0x7f2462f49c18>, bucket:<bucket>, prefix:all/specimen_datahub/q2_tube_type_reference/
13/01/2022 14:42:22 INFO Inside page_iterator loop
13/01/2022 14:42:22 DEBUG last_added: all/specimen_datahub/q2_tube_type_reference/q2_tube_type_reference.csv
13/01/2022 14:42:22 DEBUG list of temp dataframes to be created: {'ref_7_1': ['s3a://<bucket>/all/specimen_datahub/q2_tube_type_reference/q2_tube_type_reference.csv']}
13/01/2022 14:42:23 INFO Temp dataframe(s) created for: ref_7_1
13/01/2022 14:42:23 INFO Completed creation of temp view
13/01/2022 14:42:23 INFO STARTED EXECUTE_QUERY  - ( select val from specdb_orch.cntl_gbl_var where glbl_varb = 'intermediate_appcentric' )
 QUERY STRING: select val from specdb_orch.cntl_gbl_var where glbl_varb = 'intermediate_appcentric' 
13/01/2022 14:42:23 INFO  COMPLETED  EXECUTE_QUERY  WITH RESULTS : [{'val': 'gbl/intermediate/specimen_datahub_v010075/appcentric/persistent/'}]
13/01/2022 14:42:23 DEBUG split_col: Part Col
13/01/2022 14:42:23 DEBUG loader_name: /biomaterial
INSIDE ref_check METHOD
13/01/2022 14:42:23 INFO STARTED EXECUTE_QUERY  - ( select colmn_nm,file_path,filename from specdb_orch.ref_data where dtst_id=0  )
 QUERY STRING: select colmn_nm,file_path,filename from specdb_orch.ref_data where dtst_id=0  
13/01/2022 14:42:23 INFO  COMPLETED  EXECUTE_QUERY  WITH RESULTS : [{'colmn_nm': 'study', 'file_path': 's3://<bucket>/all/specimen_datahub/cohort_2_3_study/cohort_target/', 'filename': 'cohort_2_3_study_ref.csv'}]
ref_table [{'colmn_nm': 'study', 'file_path': 's3://<bucket>/all/specimen_datahub/coho
rt_2_3_study/cohort_target/', 'filename': 'cohort_2_3_study_ref.csv'}]
1 refrence records found.
ref_list []
13/01/2022 14:42:27 INFO STARTED EXECUTE_QUERY  - ( select filter_colmn_nm from specdb_orch.ref_data_col where dtst_id=7 and colmn_nm='study' )
 QUERY STRING: select filter_colmn_nm from specdb_orch.ref_data_col where dtst_id=7 and colmn_nm='study' 
13/01/2022 14:42:27 INFO  COMPLETED  EXECUTE_QUERY  WITH RESULTS : []
No ref data found
string_cond : 
13/01/2022 14:42:27 INFO sql_condition_val:  
13/01/2022 14:42:27 INFO Executing sql without ref logic.
13/01/2022 14:42:28 INFO Entering inside if statement, split_col
13/01/2022 14:42:28 DEBUG BASE_TARGET: gbl/intermediate/specimen_datahub_v010075/appcentric/persistent/operations/q2_solutions
13/01/2022 14:42:28 DEBUG printing filename: s3a://dev-dl-data-d2-us-east-1-514827/gbl/intermediate/specimen_datahub_v010075/appcentric/persistent/operations/q2_solutions/biomaterial_/file1
13/01/2022 14:42:28 INFO replaced _ before saving
13/01/2022 14:42:28 INFO Partion done: DataFrame[Anticoagulant: string, Assay Type: string, Barcode: string, Carrier: string, Collection Date: string, Collection Method: string, Collection Time: string, Comment: string, Concentration: string, Concentration Denominator Unit: string, Concentration Numerator Unit: string, Container Type: string, Created By Facility: string, Created Date: string, Created Time: string, Creation Comment: string, Current Location: string, Destination Facility: string, Final Disposition: string, Final Disposition Comment: string, Final Disposition Date: string, Manifest Number: string, Mass: string, Mass Unit: string, Number of Samples: string, Parent Sample ID: string, Parent Vendor Sample ID: string, Query Status: string, Received Date: string, Received Time: string, Receiving Comment: string, Receiving Condition: string, Receiving Facility: string, Receiving from Site Comment: string, Requisition Number: string, Sample Comment: string, Sample ID: string, Sample Tracking Code: string, Sample Type: string, Secondary Subject ID: string, Shipped Date: string, Shipped Time: string, Shipping Comment: string, Shipping Facility: string, Site Number: string, Study Number: string, Subject Group: string, Subject ID: string, Thaws: string, Timepoint: string, Tracking Number: string, Vendor: string, Vendor Sample ID: string, Visit: string, Volume: string, Volume Unit: string, Part Col: string]
13/01/2022 14:42:38 INFO total_record_count: 44610
exception in saving df: An error occurred while calling o297.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.
apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:229)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.codehaus.janino.CodeContext.extract16BitValue(CodeContext.java:700)
    at org.codehaus.janino.CodeContext.flowAnalysis(CodeContext.java:478)
```

The issue is very strange as the code runs perfectly if I am passing just dataset_id X in the for loop, so we can say that there is no issue in the dataset or the transformations I perform. But when I pair it up with other datasets(passing dataset_id X and Y from the orchestration script), the code ends at the .save of the X dataset. I am absolutely sure as the dataset X does not have dependency on any other datasets.

Can someone please help me figure out what exactly is causing this issue? I've been trying to solve this from a very long time and would really appreciate if you could take some time in reviewing the code.

P.S. I can re-iterate, if my above explanation is not clear.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post full spark traceback?

Comment: Hard to say with the small snippet of errorlog provided, would you be able to provide the full thing?

Comment: Also what confuses me is that the print "total_record_count" never shows up. It should be there, right before the error

Comment: Thank you all for taking your time in reviewing the above code. I have updated the spark traceback log on my post for more clarity.

Comment: I see a lot of loop in this code and loops with caching can cause this issue.  `cache` is useful when you are accessing to the exact dataframe again and again. For example `df.cache()` and then you do `df.groupby('A').count(); df.groupby('B').count()`.  However, if you are transforming the dataframe, you don't want to cache it in the middle of transformations.  My suggestions. 1) remove unnecessary cache. 2) simplify the code to reduce for loop. If you are transforming the files, why not read all at once and apply transformations then (split) save with partitions.

Comment: @Emma Thank you very much for your suggestion. The reason that there are many loops is that different files are saved in different location based on a logic defined in the database. Also, I have tried both ways, caching and not caching method, but the issue still persists.

Comment: I see. However, I see your for loop is by pagination.  This looks like the data is in same prefix path and same schema.  So instead of looping you can just read whole data in `spark.read.csv('s3a://xxx/bucket/sourcecentric_prefix')` and use Spark functions to transform data.  Also, how big is each `agg_df_trans`?